# Given set U is first countable or not?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, first-countable

In $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology ,the set $U =\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : -1\le x \le  1 ,  ,x \neq 0\}$ is

Choose the correct statement

$a)$ Neither hausdorff nor First  counatble

$b)$ Hausdorff

$c)$ First countable

$d)$both hausdorff and first countable

My attempt :set  $U$ can be  written as  $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$  which are  two disjoint  set, From this  i can concnclude that  $U$ is hausdorff

Im  confusing  that it is  First  countable or not ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual topology is induced by a metric and *every* metric space is first-countable.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology is also a metric space. So $\mathbb{R}$ is first countable. Hence any subspace is also first countable.

Comment: To check Hausdorffness use definition.

Answer (score 1):

> $U$ can be  written as  $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$  which are  two disjoint 
>   set, From this  i can concnclude that  $U$ is hausdorff

The fact that $U$ can be  written as  a union of two disjoint sets has **nothing** to do with the set being Hausforff or not.

For the first countable property, [google is your friend.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space)